# ImportError for module in virturalenv project directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, virtualenv, importerror

New to Python, so I'm sure this is a basic mistake, but no amount of Googling has offered a solution. I just keep seeing reminders/suggestions to do what I'm already doing...

Considering the following directory setup:

```
GAME/
    setup.py

    ChipChippersonGame/
                      __init__.py #this is empty 
                      ChipChippersonGame.py

    webapp/
          chipweb.py 
          __init__.py #this is empty

    tests/
          __init__.py #this is empty 
          app_tests.py
          tools.py

    docs/

    sessions/

    venv/
        pip-selfcheck.json
        bin/
        man/
        include/
        lib/
```

In the `chipweb.py` file in the `webapp/` directory, I'm trying to do the following:

```
from ChipChippersonGame import ChipChippersonGame
```

before running any scripts, I activate the virtual environment with:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

But when I run `chipweb.py` from outside of the `webapp/` directory, inside the `GAME` directory, I get the following error:

```
python webapp/chipweb.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webapp/chipweb.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ChipChippersonGame import ChipChippersonGame 
ImportError: No module named ChipChippersonGame
```

So I went back to my chipweb.py script and tried:

```
import ChipChippersonGame
```

and

```
from ChipChippersonGame import *
```

But still keep getting the no module found error. When I place both scripts in the same directory, there is no problem. I can call methods in the `chipweb.py` script from the `ChipChippersonGame.py` script.

I have an empty `__init__.py` in the `ChipChippersonGame` directory, but what am I doing wrong here? Why can't `chipweb.py` access the `ChipChippersonGame` script?

Answer (score 0):

You can try running your file as a module: `python -m webapp.chipweb`